# Prompt not printed after redirecting bash script output to syslog

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I found this [article](https://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2014/09/09/redirecting-bash-script-output-to-syslog/), that explains how to redirect output of a bash script to syslog. This is exactly what I needed, but there is a problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't ignore any error and return when first error occurs.
exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1
set -e  

# a list of command(s) that can fail:
chown -R user1:user1 /tmp/myappData/* 
chown -R user1:user1 /tmp/myappTmp/* 
chown -R user1:user1 /tmp/myappLog/* 
#...

exit 0
```

When I execute above script, and an **error occurs**, I see that **sometimes, the prompt doesn't return** after the script is executed. I can't figure out why this is happening. The prompt doesn't return unless I hit enter.

I am concerned that if an app uses this script, it may not get proper exit code back.

If I comment out "set -e", then the prompt **always returns** properly after the script has executed.

So my question is, what is the proper way to setup a script so that it exits on error, and logs the corresponding message to syslog?

Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Your script works really good and is ok. Do you mean that without `set -e` you see logger messages on your console after you prompt? That is just logger latency.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk. Please see my edit. The problem is that the prompt doesn't return back to user, when an error occurs; unless he/she hits enter. 

Why would that happen? There is nothing, from my understanding, in the script that would cause the prompt to not return after script is done. 

I had no problems earlier. I started having this problem after I used set -e in the script.

Comment: Typically, that just means the prompt was printed *before* the last output from your script. It was printed, it's just somewhere you aren't noticing it; when you press enter, a second prompt is printed, so it's visible. This is completely normal behavior when a program still leaves subprocesses emitting output after execution.

Comment: ...and a process substitution, like any other FIFO, is asynchronous -- time passes between when content is written by your script and when the `logger` process reads and rewrites it.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, `set -e` is [generally problematic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and behaves in [mutually-incompatible ways between different shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/). Manual error-handling is far more robust.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy. Thank you for the explanation. This means that if, for example, a program uses this script, the program won't get wait error or something, right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the `logger` pipeline is still running after your script exits, so some of the last content to be logged print *after* the parent shell has emitted its prompt. If you scroll up, you'll find the prompt hidden somewhere in that prior output.

---

If you have a very, **very** new bash, you can collect the PID of the process substitution, and `wait` for it later.

```
exec {orig_out}>&1 {orig_err}>&2 1> >(logger -s -t "${0##*/}") 2>&1; logger_pid=$!
[[ $logger_pid ]] || { echo "ERROR: Needs a newer bash" >&2; exit 1; }

cleanup() {
  exec >&$orig_out 2>&$orig_err
  wait "$logger_pid"
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

---

With an older bash, you can consider other tricks. For example, on Linux, you can use the `flock` command to try to grab exclusive access to a lockfile before exiting, after ensuring that that lock is held for as long as the logger is running:

```
log_lock=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/logger.XXXXXX")
exec >(flock -x "$log_lock" logger -s -t "${0##*/}") 2>&1

cleanup() {
  exec >/dev/tty 2>&1 || exec >/dev/null 2>&1
  flock -x "$log_lock" true
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

Comment: Good to know! I was hoping you'll answer this!

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks!