# How to make read prompt show when redirecting stderr to a process in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I currently have this issue where redirecting(`2>`) or piping(`|&`) stderr somewhere will cause `read` prompts to not print on the terminal when input is required. Instead the text is only printed after the program returned. The problem might look similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50715877/13019110), but I am not sure how it works and if we are having the same issue.

What I am trying to do is to filter the output of [pacman](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) so that it is not cluttered with warnings that I knew would be present. This is the command I execute:

`pacman -Syu --ignore="$(IFS=',';echo "${AUTOPKG[*]}")" 2> >(grep -v 'ignoring package upgrade' >&2)`

Where `${AUTOPKG[*]}` is expanded to a comma separated list of package I want to ignore at that moment. `grep -v` filters out the unnecessary warnings and redirect the output back to the terminal.

In addition, I have also tried using the `read` utility to narrow the problem down to stderr only as redirecting stdout alone will still let the prompt through. I have no more clues from here on though, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The shell writes the prompt to standard error; you can't selectively redirect some strings written to standard error to one place while (re)directing other strings elsewhere, at least not without writing your own parser to read from your shell's standard error and write to multiple files.

Comment: There is no `read` in your command. Redirecting stderr to stdin and filtering them altogether is not an option for you?

Comment: @user3132194 No there is no read in the command, but since I assumed grep behaved the same as read, I figured that other utilities might behave the same. And ideally combining both streams is neither ideal nor would it help the situation once I knew what happened here. The problem is that a newline is not printed, so grep was eternally waiting for the line to finish and refuse to print.

Answer (score 0):

So I have experimented with the commands and stuff and found that the line is printed to the file descriptor just that it is not printing it out because it still haven't hit a newline, so I realized I can use `read -rn1` to read the input and pass that to grep with a timeout that prints the buffer out if too much time is passed. Here is the drop-in replacement function for grep:

```sh
timeoutGrep()
{
    local string  pid_sleep=0
    while IFS= read -rN1 ch ;do
        if (( $pid_sleep )) && [ -e /proc/$pid_sleep ] ;\
            then kill $pid_sleep ;\
            else string='' ;fi
        string+="$ch"

        if [ "$ch" = $'\n' ] ;then
            grep "$@" <(printf '%s' "$string")
            pid_sleep=0
        else
            sleep 0.5 && grep "$@" <(printf '%s' "$string") | tr -d '\n' &
            pid_sleep=$!
        fi
    done
}
```

The rundown of what this function does is to read a char and append it to a buffer, then depend on the character read: '\n'? then send the line to grep immediately, since we know the line is finished, then tell the next iteration it didn't call a background process; or not '\n'? then create a background grep that is delayed, tell the next iteration what the pid of it is. An iteration is advanced when a new character is read, if the background process was successfully run it will be terminated, otherwise if it is 0, no background process was created, in both cases clean the buffer. If it is neither of both cases, assume the background process still hasn't grepped the string, kill it before it does, then carry on to continue the loop.

It seems to be working for now though it has some delays and may mess up the order of the message. I also tried using the timeout option in `read` but it seems to stop the running process somehow which I suspect is due to closing of the file descriptor.

Comment: It looks very complicated, so i did not read it all closely. But dont you try to reinvernt `grep --line-buffered`?

Comment: @user3132194 I didn't know what it means but after a bit of searching, no, it is not `grep --line-buffered`. Will edit for more clarification.